# Regex python find whole line where there are multiple commas

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to set an address pattern for regex to find. Best i could come up with is the number of comas.
Here is the part of a text and I want to match the second line:

```
SIA "JET TRAVEL"
Dzirnieku iela 15, Lidosta ,,Riga”, Marupes novads, LV-1053, Latvija
40003789713
```

I have tried:

```
address_pattern = '.*(.*?),+.*\n?'
address = re.findall(address_pattern, ocr_text, flags=re.I|re.M)
for match in address:
    print(match)
```

Shouldn't it go whole line since it starts with .* and ends with .*\n. then (.*?) should include all possible values (since there could be words, numbers and whitespaces in between) **and** comma (,)+ - i need the line to contain multiple commas.

I have also tried ,{3} to indicate I need 3 commas, but it failed.

All and any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I don't understand.... what is the input and what is the desired output?

Comment: @Alexander. Input is the first code I have entered and the desired output is the second line of that code ( I wanted to match 'Dzirnieku iela 15, Lidosta ,,Riga”, Marupes novads, LV-1053, Latvija') sorry if the question wasnt phrased well. Found the solution tho! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well I am glad you figured it out because I still don't understand

Comment: @FoxSinofGreed if you found the solution, please *do* share it or accept one of the answers below. "I figured it out" won't be useful for future readers coming across this post.

Comment: @fsimonjetz sorry, but my solution actually worked for this 1 scenario only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `re.M(ULTILINE)` flag, you don't need to account for the `\n`. Instead, use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of lines, respectively (different from their default behavior). `re.I` has no effect here. Note that `{2,}` and the like mean "2 or more *consecutive* commas".

```py
re.findall('^.*,{2,}.*$', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: how can I find a line that contain 2 or 3 commas? Without them being consecutive

Comment: @FoxSinofGreed In that case maybe you don't need regular expressions at all but something like `[line for line in text.splitlines() if line.count(',') >= 3]`?